# How can I display an image within a node with an SRC value that incorporates a URL taken from another field?

Tags: views, theming, media, nodes

I'm creating a directory of useful (web based) resources for a community. I'd like to use Drupal 7, but can use Drupal 6 if absolutely necessary. I don't mind installing any additional useful modules.

I'd like to create a node with a link field that stores the URL of the useful resource.

I'd like to display a screenshot of this URL, using [WordPress's mshots feature](http://www.labnol.org/internet/webpage-screenshots-dynamic/19341/#captureform), as part of the node.

So, as an example, the value of the link field would be:

> http://mashable.com/guidebook/twitter/

Within my content type template, or as an image field, or however you suggest I do it, this URL would need to be encoded and inserted into an image SRC value to give:

> http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2Fguidebook%2Ftwitter%2F?w=500

Which shows a 500px wide screenshot of that URL.

What do you think would be the best way of doing this? I could use 'rewrite the output of this field' in Views, but I'd like the screenshot to be shown in the node view too.

Comment: Sorry for butchering those URLs with the space after the http:// but as a user without any built up reputation points I'm not allowed to post more than one link per post, even if they're automatically generated links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom 'screenshot' formatter for the link field. Further info for [D6](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-custom-cck-fields) and [D7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - I will look into it and mark as an answer if appropriate. [http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) looks useful for me too.

Comment: Or http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters if I go down the module route. I like the idea of creating a module which I could contribute back to the Drupal community.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've just set up a custom formatter using the custom_formatters module.

Comment: There's a Ctools friendly export at http://pastebin.com/umVscAnH for anyone trying to do something similar to this.